# Angular expression to check if model is array or object

Tags: angularjs

How can I check if an angular model is an array or an object? Is there a built in or do I have to write a filter `isArray` with [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

[`{{[] | isArray}}`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isArray)  doesn't work

Comment: google ? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isArray

Comment: wah. didn't find it. thanks!

Comment: this doesn't work in an expression

Comment: `angular.isArray` can be used only in javascript code. Tell us why you need to check and how you will use it.

Comment: BTW there is a very interesting page where you can find lots of useful stuff... it's called angular API docs http://docs.angularjs.org/api

Comment: No need to be rude. I want to check if an object is an array in an expression. Currently I'm using an simple filter and wondered if there is a built in for it (https://gist.github.com/mren/12cd33637e9c54641acc).

Comment: `scope.isArray = angular.isArray`

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `angular.isArray` function.  It's built-in inside Angularjs.

If you want to use this function inside your template, you have to create a custom filter: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Example of what you want:

```
angular.module('...', []).filter('isArray', function() {
  return function (input) {
    return angular.isArray(input);
  };
});
```

Then you can use the filter inside your template:

```
{{ myVar | isArray }}
```

Comment: thanks. You're right, this is working. Do you know if there is a built in to check for this or do I need to roll my own filter? This looks like a basic check

Comment: The filter does not exist in Angular. You have to code it. If your problem is solved, don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can also add underscore/lodash to the rootScope and use it:

```
_ = require('lodash')

angular.module('app',[])
.run(function($rootScope){ 
   $rootScope._ = _
})
```

And in the template:

```
<div ng-show="$root._.isArray(foo)"> 
   <label> First element of Foo </label>
   <span> {{ $root._.first(foo) }} </span>
</div>
```

The benefits - you have to add lodash only in one place, and it will be available everywhere. You can use many other things the same way, like `Math` functions for example. Just be reasonable and don't put too much javascript into expressions.