# Detect array in angular template

Tags: angularjs

I have an array that I am iterating through and displaying. Sometimes, however, the item it finds is an array. I'd like to do something different with this, using an ng-if. I am unsure how to do this easily. It seems like a common issue but there doesn't appear to be an easy solution.

Comment: Can you expand your question more? What would you like to do if the item is an array? Can you provide a demo code (plunker)?

Comment: Hi. Did you find a better way to solve this issue thant defining a home made filter ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Angular.isArray()` ([see doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isArray)) but it does not exist as a already defined filter so you might need to define your own.

Something like that :

```
angular.module('...', []).filter('isArray', function() {
  return function (input) {
    return angular.isArray(input);
  };
});
```

And then in your template usimply use `{{ myVar | isArray }}`.

My only concerne is ... is it really clean to do so ? I don't know but this will solve your problem.

By the way, was already asked on StakcOverFlow : [Angular expression to check if model is array or object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356582/angular-expression-to-check-if-model-is-array-or-object)