# Angular expression is unable to tell variable type using constructor property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using an angular expression, I tried to show if a scope variable is an array.

I tried to use `variable.constructor === Array` for checking the same, but in expression always showing `false` as result.

When I used a scope function to `return variable.constructor === Array`, I got the correct result.

Can someone tell, why expression behaves in this manner. 
Also, how same check can be done as an inline expression statement.

Checkout the Plunker demonstrating same problem, [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/6j4a94yNGpzzBEkKJAON) 

 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing known as Array, so you are essentially comparing a value to undefined.

To test that a value is an array, you can use the in-built Angular function called isArray().

See the answer here for more information: [Angular expression to check if model is array or object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356582/angular-expression-to-check-if-model-is-array-or-object)

Answer (score 3):

There is no variable named `Array` in your scope, so the expression `variable.constructor === Array` is basically returning the result of `variable.constructor === undefined`.

That's why it's always false.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `Array.isArray(variable)` in JS.

Further info [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)