# Angularjs checking typeof array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some data which can be string or array. So if it is a string, I want to display it, and if it is an array, I want to display length of it.

This how data look like:
[image] or [image]

Trying to check data type of:

```
<div class="properties">{{typeof(row.contact)=="object" ? 1 : 2}}</div>//with 1 and 2 its more simplify.
```

But in both cases it will display `2`. Why is it so and how can I fixed it?

P.S.

```
 {{angular.isArray(value)? 1 : 2}}//result the same
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular expression to check if model is array or object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356582/angular-expression-to-check-if-model-is-array-or-object)

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez  Trying to use angular.isArray but result is the same as I write

Comment: Strings and Arrays in JavaScript are technically an object. You probably want to check if it is an `instanceof` a `String` or `Array`

Comment: @Hoyen yes, but operator typeof may return "string" or "object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try define in controller

```
 $scope.isArray = angular.isArray;
```

then use

```
  {{isArray(value)? 1 : 2}}//result the same
```